# Как при окончании hover сделать что бы медленно вернулся элемент?

Tags: css

Есть такая структура:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  white-space: pre;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

p:first-child {
  z-index: 100;
}

div:hover p:first-child {
  width: 3%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out .5s;
  background: #888;
}

a {
  color: #fefefe;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <a href="#"> Это ссылка</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#"> Смотреть пример</a>
  </p>

</div>
```

Но как видно, кнопка медленно открывается но закрывается резко,быстро.
Сам вопрос в том как сделать что бы в исходное состояние она вернулась так же как и открылась? совсем выехал ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите transition из 
`div:hover p:first-child` и поставьте его в `div p:first-child`.